# How to have automatically wrapping text (line break) when the text is too long for an HTML table cell?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

if I have an HTML table cell that contains some text (more words). This table has a **fixed layout**. What can I do to **automatically wrap** the text (line break) when the text is too long to fit in the cell?

For example, if a cell contains the text: `This text is too long for my cell's width` I want it to show something like:

```
This text is
too long for
my cell's width
```

Is it possible obtain this behavior in some way?

Comment: That is the default behaviour of a table cell. Do you have `white-space: nowrap;` in your CSS?

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;` along with fixed widths, is what you are after.

Comment: Demo -- > http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/pckca6ug/1/

Comment: It would be better if you could show your use-case in the question.